# How Hibernate's enver @AuditTable and @CreationTimestamp and different date format for main and public schema cause wrong values in the main schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, hibernate-annotations, creation-timestamp

We have an audit schema and `Hibernate enver` to audit the data:

```
spring:
 jpa:
  org:
    hibernate:
      envers:
        default_schema: audit
```

and here are the anoontations.

BaseEntity:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
            ,parameters = {
            @Parameter( name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class", value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy")
    })
    @Column(name="id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;


    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;    
}
```

other entities extend it, as well as the audit set up on it too.

Say, Contractor entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "audit", value = "contractor")
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
@Table(name = "contractor", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "contractor_upi_uq", columnNames = {"upi"})})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(comment = "Contractor data", appliesTo = "contractor")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {}, callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude = {"contract", "billingAccount", "legalForm", "services", "contractorType", "serviceGroups"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"contract", "billingAccount", "legalForm", "services", "contractorType", "serviceGroups"})
public class Contractor extends BaseEntity {    
//specific fields are ommited as the problem are related to the field from the Base entity    
}
```

or ServiceOrder entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "audit", value = "services_order")
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
@Table(name = "services_order")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(comment = "Services order", appliesTo = "services_order")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {}, callSuper = true)
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class ServicesOrder  extends BaseEntity {
//the same for the internals of this entity
}
```

We notices, that the entities of the same time of creation have different `created_at` values, for example:

[image]

The `created_at` column has type `timestamp without timezone`, for some entries it was in the local timezone, while in others +3h, in others -3h (our timezone is +3 UTC).

That happened on UAT db, but never happened on dev db, where all entries are from the same time.

I tired to find what the problem correlates with and have fount that despite the `created_at` has the same `timestamp without timezone` for the different tables of the main `public` schema, the same and corresponding `created_at` field has different type in audit `schema` for some tables. If the audit's field has type  `timestamp without timezone`, the date in the field of the main schema is as expected and fits the local timezone time. If the `audit` schema's field created_at has type  `timestamp with timezone`, the value in the main `public` schema's is -3 h (not as expected).

[image]

What could be the real reason for that? Does @CreationTimestamp really interacts with the enver and audit table before produce the output date to the main schema table? Is there a way to work this around not even touching the audit schema>